# Override the default color of the asterisk in the label of an Angular material input field

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have angular material date picker control in my web app.
By default it shows that the date field is mandatory by putting the 'asterisk' following the mat-label. The below code ilustrates that case:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" enabled>
              <mat-label enabled>DOB</mat-label>
              <input class="asterisk_input" formControlName="dob" #ref matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker"
                placeholder="Choose a date" required />
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-hint>YYYY-MM-DD</mat-hint>
              <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="false" [stepHour]="1"
                [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1" [touchUi]="false" [color]="undefined" [enableMeridian]="false"
                [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="true">
              </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
              <mat-error *ngIf="f['dob'].errors">Invalid DOB</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
```

... so it looks on the screen like this:

[image]

I would like the star (asterisk) to be displayed in `red` colour.

I have tried this css:

```
span.mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

... but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to force it to be `red`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out you have to use `:host ::ng-deep` in the local stylesheet of your component, otherwise your css-selector won't be applied. Additionally, to specifically target the asterisk rather than the entire label text, you have to include `.mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker` in your selector.

In case you use `CSS`, add the following to you local component's stylesheet:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label .mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker {
    color: red;
}
```

In case you use `SCSS`, add the following selector instead:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
    .mdc-floating-label {
        .mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Big thank you. Would you mind to explain :host and ::ng-deep?

Comment: Also how did you come up with the sequence:  `:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
  .mdc-floating-label {
      .mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker {...}`. Using Debugger I came up with this sequence: `.mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker .mdc-floating-label--required .ng-star-inserted` - which is not working.

Comment: `:host` is a selector for the *host* element that matches your component selector. for example, `app-root` and you write your styles in `app.component.css`. there your `:host` selector will apply styles in on your `app-root` element.

Comment: If you want your component styles to cascade to all child elements of a component, but not to any other element on the page, you can do so using by combining the `:host` with the `::ng-deep` selector. If you just `::ng-deep`, your styles would globally apply to the entire application which we usually want to avoid.

Comment: How I came up with this sequence? As a first step I added `:host ::ng-deep`, then I realized that the entire label gets colored red instead of just the asterix. So I had a look at the dom and looked for a child-element which targets exclusively the asterix and `.mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker` immediately caught my eye.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker` to style the asterisk and change `color` to what you want. Here's an example:

[image]

### Encapsulation

*But if you're NOT writing this style in a global stylesheet*, it **won't** work. This is due to the way that Angular components **encapsulates** every style rule in your component-level CSS and so that your styles don't go out of their scope, i.e. Material Design components.

But here you actually want to work around this encapsulation and one way is to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `@Component`'s `encapsulation` metadata:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

or to use `::ng-deep` before your CSS selector. `::ng-deep` simply disables view-encapsulation for that particular CSS rule, meaning you can access deeper levels of your components, i.e:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-form-field-required-marker { /* your code here */ }
```